# Mapping uint to value within min/max set

Tags: c#, interval

I have a method that transforms any input `uint` into a `[min,max]` set. I am looking for improvements on the function, specifically to get rid of the `input == uint.MaxValue` case.

```
public static uint NumberInRange(uint input, uint min, uint max)
{
    decimal divider = uint.MaxValue / (decimal)max;
    if (input == uint.MaxValue)
        return (uint)max;

    var i = (uint)(Math.Floor(input / divider) + min);
    return i;
}
```

Let me know if you see any ways to improve this function, or if you think that there is any subtle bug within it.

I am basically just looking into a way to map a bigger set `[0,uint.MaxValue]` into a smaller set `[min,map]`.

Let's say the inputs are:

`NumberInRange(0, 10, 100)` - I should get 10

`NumberInRange(uint.MaxValue, 10, 100)` - I should get 100

For any number in between, I want them to be mapped "equally" between members of the set.

Let's say I put in a number that gives value between 0 and 1:

```
for (input / (uint.MaxValue/max)))
```

All 0.xxxx values should map to `min` (instead of getting `min` for numbers between 0 and 0.5, and `min`+1 for 0.5-1.5, etc) in order to see equal distribution in mapping (hence `Math.Floor`).

I think the function does it's job pretty well.  I was just looking to see if I can eliminate that `if (input == uint.MaxValue)` case since it's a weird edge case (for which result is `max`+1). This is also one thing that can be nitpicked from math standpoint - all members of the set will get mapped from *n* elements, while the last member will get mapped from n+1 elements (because of this special if case).

Comment: you should write some edge-case unit-tests but I don't think that you need the part where you check vor max-Value at all

Comment: I would like some more clarity on what the code is supposed to do. For example, what should `NumberInRange(1000, 10, 100)` return? (and why!). I feel like there is a bug, and that for the divider, the code should be `... = uint.MaxValue / (decimal)(max - min)`

Comment: Code does not behave properly when `min` and `max` are close to each other and significantly greater than zero. Perhaps the input labeled `max` is supposed to represent the interval size?

Comment: @Snowbody no, I specifically need it to work in [min,max] set (not interval size). If you can provide me with exact values for input,min,max that it doesn't work for you, I can test and try to fix it.

Comment: using your existing code, `input = uint.maxValue/2, min=100005, max=100006` should result in either 100005 or 100006 depending on your conventions, but it doesn't. It gets 3000017.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend considering this using more explicitly the [Two-Point Equation of a Line](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form). Your code is basically doing the same thing, but thinking more explicitly in terms of the underlying mathematics would help avoid errors or extra complication.

Here is how I would implement this:

```
public static uint LinearTransform(uint x, uint x1, uint y1, uint x2, uint y2) {
    ulong a = (ulong)(y2 - y1)*(x - x1);
    uint b = (x2 - x1);
    return (uint)(a/b) + (a%b*2 >= b)?1:0 + y2;
}
```

I don't actually know C#, so it is likely that the code is not syntactically correct, or breaks the style rules of the language, but it should get the point across.

The `(a%b*2 >= b)?1:0` term is to compensate for the way integer division always truncates to zero. This will make it instead round up if the fractional part would be 1/2 or more, so we don't need to do any floating point computations.

This function can then be used to perform your original task by calling it as `LinearTransform(input, 0, min, uint.MaxValue, max)`.

Comment: The line `uint a = (y2 - y1)*(x - x1);` is subject to integer overflow, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Snowbody I have fixed the problem by using a `ulong` to store that product.

Comment: yep, that works

Answer (score 3):

In C-style languages, it's much more natural to specify an integer range half-open. Think about a `for` loop. The range is specified by the lowest value in the range, and **the lowest value that is not in the range**, aka one more than the highest value in the range. This is to avoid the off-by-one error you're experiencing. (Failure to follow this convention causes no end of trouble to people trying to write binary search routines) So I'd rewrite your code as follows:

```
public static uint NumberInRange(uint input, uint min, uint maxPlusOne)
{
    if (input == uint.MaxValue)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input");
    decimal divider = uint.MaxValue / (decimal)(maxPlusOne-min);

    var i = (uint)(Math.Floor(input / divider) + min);
    return i;
}
```

Yes, the code is exactly the same (except I put the missing `-min` into the denominator of `divider`), just how you call it is different. For one, `uint.MaxValue` is not allowed. Instead of mapping [0,`uint.MaxValue`] to [`min`,`max`] it maps [0,`uint.MaxValue`) to [`min`,`maxPlusOne`). Note that both intervals are half-open.

Answer (score 2):

This code implicitly types the `i` variable. Why? You already know that `i` will be a `uint` type. [Microsoft recommends against this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

> The use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more
>   difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C#
>   documentation generally uses var only when it is required.

Also, `i` is a very poor variable name.

These are both moot points though, because that variable is entirely superfluous. That part of the function can be rewritten to directly return the value of the expression.

```
return (uint)(Math.Floor(input / divider) + min);
```

Comment: I don't know if you actually don't know what `var` does, or if you're just using confusing terminology, but C# `var` is very different from [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type) in other languages.

Comment: I fail to see how I'm confused @svick. [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) implicitly types and it seems unnecessary when `i` is known to be a `uint`.

Comment: Yes, but calling `var` variant is confusing for those who know the term variant from other languages (like VB 6). And I've never seen it called this way.

Comment: They're very different internal implementations, but the same concept. I don't think it's as confusing as you're making it out to be @svick. A variant type is an implicit type declaration. What's so confusing about that? I'm not trying to be difficult. I'm just trying to figure out how to improve my answer.

Comment: No, variant type is not implicit type declaration. variant is more like `object` in C#, it can store anything. With variant, you can first assign an `int` to a variable and then assign `string` to the same variable. You can't do that with `var`.

Comment: Yes. Different implementation; Same concept. When you use `var` (or a variant in a different language), you're saying "I don't know what type this will be until it runs. We clearly know that the result of this statement will be a `uint` so it should not be used.

Comment: No! That's not what `var` means at all. It means “compiler, figure out what this type is at compile time, so that I don't have to spell it out”.

Comment: It's a subtle difference. Thank you for educating me, but it's still an ill advised thing to do.

Comment: @ckuhn203 do you mean that var is ill advised?  I actually thought it was recommended practice when the type of the variable being created is obvious at creation i.e. var i = new TestClass() see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: I was going off of the last paragraph of this [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx), which also explains that var != variant.